# В книге Герберта Шилдта по Java 8 есть пример с кодом, разложите по полочкам, если не сложно

Tags: java

В общем, вот этот код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        outer: for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                if(j > i) {
                    System.out.println();
                    continue outer;
                }
                System.out.print(" " + (i * j));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

ВОТ ЧТО ОН ВЫВОДИТ:

```
0 1
0 2 4
0 3 6 9
0 4 8 12 16
0 5 10 15 20 25
0 6 12 18 24 30 36
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Comment: Давайте поконкретнее, что именно неясно? Я уверен, что в книге есть объяснение всего, что встречается в этого коде.

Comment: Неясно из-за чего он выводит такой ответ. К примеру я читаю этот код так: Пока i < 10, j < 10 и если j > i - вывести System.out.println();. С этого момента дальше не понятно, что конкретно пропускает оператор Continue и как правильно прочитать это код. Также с чего вдруг берутся эти цифры в выводе кода.

Comment: Ну подумайте, что произойдет если j < i.

Comment: У меня выводятся 0, только я не пойму почему, мы этим двум переменным присвоили значение равные 0, как тогда j может быть  больше или меньше i ?

Comment: Этим переменным не присваивали 0, а вам нужно вернуться назад и перечитать главу про циклы for.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ). Сам бы так никогда не сделал

Comment: Ну так, хорошо, выполняется инициализация, а не присваивание, все равно не пойму, как и почему меняются значения в переменных i и j.

Comment: Потому что цикл for.

Comment: Хорошо, при каждом повторе цикла мы увеличиваем значение на 1, но как тогда i > j, если изначально они равны ?

Comment: Потому что "при каждом повторе цикла мы увеличиваем значение на 1". Говорю же, перечитайте главу про циклы. Там наверняка есть примеры с объяснениями.

Comment: Да нету там них*я, там описываются базовые принципы работы с ними, а так как работают эти циклы и что в них происходит, этого не описывается. Мне не понятно почему j > i, что этому способствует, если мы их в начале инициализировали как равные переменные, то из-за чего тогда одна вдруг стала больше другой?

Comment: ПОТОМУ ЧТО В КАЖДОЙ ИТЕРАЦИИ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ УВЕЛИЧИВАЕТСЯ НА 1. И НАПРИМЕР 1 УЖЕ БОЛЬШЕ ЧЕМ 0. ВОТ И ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ ЧТО j СТАЛО БОЛЬШЕ i.

Comment: А i получается не увеличивается из-за оператора continue ?

Comment: тут два цикла и эти переменные увеличиваются независимо друг друга. оператор continue здесь влияет на то, что печатается только половина таблицы умножения, а не вся она.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, тут можно как-то лайк поставить или что-то такое, чтобы тебе какой-то  "плюс" в аккаунт залетел

Comment: можно, но мне для этго надо написать ответ, а мне неохота. Так что если действительно все понятно, то и хорошо.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Можешь посоветовать какую-то более легкую книгу по Java? А то в этой не понятно что происходит

Comment: @MaximKapko, здравствуйте, в свое время начинал с Шилдта, но очень тяжело пошло и решил взять Java Библиотека профессионала. Она хоть по 7 джаве, но книга была понятна новичку, плюс их 2 части и можно узнать полезные вещи не только о джаве, а и о смежных вещах, но подобии xml и прчоего. Если хотите полегче, то это очень хороший вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, первая строчка получается так. Итерация во внешнем цикле: `i = 0`. Итерация во внутреннем цикле `j = 0`. Условие `if` не выполняется, поэтому в консоль выводится произведение `i * j`.

Дальше начинается новая итерация во внутреннем цикле `j = 1`. При этом во внешнем цикле итерация `i = 0` продолжается. Условие `if (j > i)` = `true`, а значит выполнятся `блок кода if`. Переход на новую строку и переход на метку `outer`, которая стоит на внешнем цикле.
Получился досрочный выход из внутреннего цикла.

Теперь начинается новая итерация во внешнем цикле `i = 1`. А во внутреннем цикле все начинается с начала. Итерация `j = 0`. На этой итерации условие `if` не выполняется и поэтому в консоль снова выводится произведение `i * j`. Тоже самое происходит и на следующей итерации `j = 1`. А вот на третьей итерации `j = 2`, снова выполняется условие `if` и происходит досрочный выход из внутреннего цикла во внешний. Где снова увеличивается `i` и теперь уже `j` примет три разных значения, прежде чем станет больше чем `i`. Поэтому в третьей строке вывода уже три значения.

Дальше все по той же схеме. На каждой итерации внешнего цикла `i` будет увеличиваться на единицу и, соответственно, будет увеличиваться количество выводимых в консоль произведений `i * j`.

Вообще в данном коде строка `continue outer;` выполняет роль оператора `break`. Если вы замените ее на `break`, то увидите, что результат работы программы не изменится. И можно даже убрать метку перед внешним циклом, т.к. она больше не будет использоваться.

Это очень хороший пример, чтобы начать осваивать дебагер. Пошагово проходить работу кода и смотреть, что происходит. Удачи вам!

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что все так объяснили, вам тоже удачи!